# Simple CSS Transition making font skip at Peak of scaling

Tags: css, transition

Can some one help me sold my problem with my transition on my List. When you hover on the text the font skips at the peak of the hover?? Why is that and how can I make it smooth all the way through the transition.

HTML

```
<ul class="long-lists">
<li><a href="target=&amp;pid=468&amp;did=0&amp;tab=0">Arts and Humanities</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.ymcabwv.org/childcare">Childcare and Early Childhood Education</a></li>
<li><a href="target=&amp;pid=374&amp;did=0&amp;tab=0">Free 7<sup>th</sup> Grade Memberships</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.ymcabwv.org/program-pages/ymca-kindergarten-academy">Full Day Kindergarten in West Chester</a></li>
<li><a href="target=&amp;pid=867&amp;did=0&amp;tab=0">Jennersville Theatre Programs</a></li>
<li><a href="target=&amp;pid=373&amp;did=0&amp;tab=0">Believe and Achieve</a></li>
<li><a href="target=&amp;pid=675&amp;did=0&amp;tab=0">Youth Council</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.long-lists li a{
    font-size: 1.15em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0060af;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height: 190%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.long-lists li a:hover{
    transform: scale(1.01);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.01);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.01);
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0089d0;
    line-height: 190%;
}
```

Included the Codepen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oFHGb
Thanks

Comment: wat? you should make a jsfiddle, because i don't think most people here are going to know what "the font skips at the peak of the hover" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Tried it on fiddle. Saw no "skipping".

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oFHGb , Could be a issue with the version of chrome 37 at work....

Comment: I can also see it (FF 33) but do not have any constructive solution

Comment: Chrome 39 beta works perfectly.

Comment: Chrome 38.0.2125.104, smooth transition with no issues.